# PHP XAMPP local network issues

Tags: php, css, internet-explorer, xampp

I'm developing a small database system for my company. The PC (Win7-pro) is connected to the local intranet.

I'm having a big issue right now with IE10.

When I start Apache and MySQL in XAMPP and go to:

```
http://localhost/control/
```

Everything works great for Chrome, FF, and IE8, IE9, and IE10

But...

When I replace my computer name (ussatpc456.emea.northward.com) with "localhost":

```
http://ussatpc456.emea.northward.com/control/
```

It works great in Chrome and FF but for some reason IE8, 9, and 10 loses **some** of the CSS (not all of it). But a good majority of it.

And this is ONLY for IE.

Is this another one of those infamous IE bugs where I have to create special css for IE users? If so, does anyone have any input??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write a conditional IE stylesheet, if done correctly you can write your code so it doesn't have to use computability view. My favorite article on this is Chis Coyier's article on [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)

Comment: Awesome! Do you know of any FREE browser emulators?? I currently have IE10 on my machine and had to find a co-worker with IE8 to test it. I would like to be able to test it without confirming with a co-worker.

Comment: I don't know of any emulators. You can try [BrowserStack](http://browserstack.com) I use that for all my testing

Comment: Or you can setup a virtual machine

Answer (score 0):

Ah...figured it out...I had to un-check the "Display Intranet sites in Compatibility View"

This is going to suck...I can't tell all users to uncheck this.